# Clicking a particular checkbox using cypress

Tags: angular, unit-testing, cypress

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items>
<div>
    <mat-checkbox
    id="checbox_1"
    [(ngModel)]="item.checked"
    (ngModelChange)="onCheckboxChecked()"
    ></mat-checkbox>
   </div>
</div>
```

With the above code it displays list of items with checkbox attached to each item. I'm trying to click a specific checkbox and test using cypress. I need some help in doing this. Thank you.

Tried

```
cy.get('#mat-checkbox-1-input').click(); (unable to find element)
cy.get('#checbox_1').click() (is not visible because it has CSS property: `position: fixed` and it's being covered by another element:)
```

Comment: all your elements have this : `id="checbox_1"`, maybye it should be unique

Comment: yes, I'm trying on how to do that.

Comment: `<div *ngFor="let item of items; itemIndex=index">` then `id="checkbox_" + itemIndex`

Answer (score 4):

I  finally achieved through this.

```
    cy.get('input[type="checkbox"]').eq(2).check({ force: true })
```